# GitHub readme markdown to include bullet points inside of table

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I am trying to put bullet points inside of a GitHub text box for the READme.

I know how to do them separately. For example to create the gray textbox I can do:

```
   item1
   item2
   ```

To create bullet points I can do:

```
* item1
* item2
```

However if I try and place the bullet points inside of the table, the literal syntax for the bullet points shows up, rather than the bullet points. I have tried escaping the bullet point characters.

How do I get bullet points inside of the table?

Comment: I have been searching for this for quite a long time. Hope somebody answers this. Thank you.

Comment: That does not look anything like GFM [Table](https://github.github.com/gfm/#tables-extension-) syntax.

Comment: I meant to write gray textbox rather than 'table'. It sounds like the gray textbox is meant for code though.

Answer (score 4):

The GitHub Flavored Markdown [Spec](https://github.github.com/gfm/#tables-extension-) plainly states:

> Block-level elements cannot be inserted in a table.

Of course, [lists](https://github.github.com/gfm/#lists) are [block-level](https://github.github.com/gfm/#blocks-and-inlines) elements, and therefore they cannot be inserted in a table.

Generally the way to get around such restrictions in Markdown is to use raw HTML. However, a raw HTML list would be a [HTML block](https://github.github.com/gfm/#html-blocks), which is also a block-level element and not allowed in a table. Therefore, you would need to use raw HTML for the entire table.